# How to build my own gantt chart with JS

Tags: javascript, html, gantt-chart

I am about to see if Javascript in a HTML5 canvas is capable of building my own gantt chart. The chart should provide drag and drop. Is there a library that gives me a good basis? so I don't have to build everything from scratch.

Comment: Perhaps a starting point ? or example ? -> http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~brousse1/Libraries/RGraph/examples/gantt.html

Comment: thank you. I really like that and already playing around

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[**jsGantt**](http://www.jsgantt.com/)

> A fully featured **gantt chart component** built entirely in **Javascript**,
>   **CSS** and **AJAX**. No images required.
>
> Features include: Tasks & Collapsible Task Groups Dependencies, Task
>   Completion, Task Color, Milestones, Resources, Dynamic Loading of
>   Tasks, Dynamic change of format (day/week/month), Load Gantt from XML
>   file.
>
> You can view a live example at **[http://www.jsgantt.com](http://www.jsgantt.com/#tDownload)**

Some other libraries:

https://www.bryntum.com/products/gantt-for-extjs/

http://www.jsgantt.com/#tDownload

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried googling for some examples? There are dozens out there. [jsgantt](http://jsgantt.com/) and  [dhtmlxgantt](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/index.shtml) are the first two I found without too much trouble.