# Building gantt charts in javascript

Tags: javascript, web, gantt-chart

I want to build a gantt chart on web . I came across the link [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701325/how-to-build-my-own-gantt-chart-with-js) but I couldn't get much from those links and by googling  it I came across many repo. where it's code is made public . Is there any other resource to be a little helpful for making a gantt chart ..

#### please suggest some of implementation details

looking to this much amount of code is difficult, whereas anything regarding ganttchart is most welcomed

Answer (score 2):

I've used this in a few projects and it works very well and quite easy to configure.

This is open source also :)

http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/

Comment: It appears to be static can u please suggest something that is sort of dynamic [link](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/01_basic.html) any insight how to implement the dropdown and simutaneous charting system

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by static, I've used this to create dynamic reports using ajax, php and pasing this JSON from a select drop list that depending on the option using jquery triggers the above

Answer (score 1):

- http://www.rgraph.net/

  http://www.rgraph.net/docs/gantt.html

  RGraph is a HTML5 based open charts library built for web charts and **supports over twenty different types of visualisation**. Using the  tag, RGraph creates these charts inside the web browser using JavaScript.

  - Quicker pages and less web server load
  - Smaller page sizes and faster websites.

Answer (score 0):

A fully featured gantt chart component built entirely in Javascript, CSS and AJAX. No images required.

Features include: Tasks & Collapsible Task Groups Dependencies, Task Completion, Task Color, Milestones, Resources, Dynamic Loading of Tasks, Dynamic change of format (day/week/month), Load Gantt from XML file.

You can view a live example at http://www.jsgantt.com

Some other libraries:

http://www.fusioncharts.com/goodies/fusioncharts-free/chart-gallery/show.asp?id=44

http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~brousse1/Libraries/RGraph/examples/gantt.html

http://www.bryntum.com/products/gantt/

http://www.jsgantt.com/#tDownload

Hope this helps.