# Gantt Chart with multiple task based from database

Tags: php, jquery, html, smarty, gantt-chart

I'm in need of a Gantt chart for my project that will display like the chart below, And data must be based from database. I have been looking for one but it only support one block per row.
 My requirements is to have multiple block per row to avoid redundancy of the 'Name'  
any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build my own gantt chart with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701325/how-to-build-my-own-gantt-chart-with-js)

Comment: @Darragh that one support one block per row only.. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [RadiantQ jQuery Gantt](http://radiantq.com/products/jquery-gantt-package/jquery-gantt-package-features/). There are 2 Gantt flavors, what you need is the Resource Gantt (aka FlexyGantt). Here is the [online demo](http://demos.radiantq.com/jQueryGanttDemo/Demo.htm) - pick the Flexy Gantt samples in the list on the left.

There are a number of features you will like:

- Your resource list can also be a hierarchy of tasks (instead of just a flat list).
- Besides just plotting, you can interact with the tasks dynamically - move them, resize them, move between resources, etc.
- The task times can be rounded to fit within days if necessary. You can also set up a schedule which would dictate that tasks cannot be set on "weekends/holidays".
- If there are overlapping tasks, that can be highlighted with automatically shrinking tasks.
- Thousands of tasks can be handled easily because this supports virtualization.
- Tasks out of view can be cued with the "browse to task" cues.
- Time line is fully zoomable as well.

There are a whole lot of other features as well, I am sure you won't be disappointed.

Praveen